# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called. UITableViewController subclassed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Tried programming more in an OO manner.

NOTE:

Seems the problem is related to having a UITableView(which is a type of scrollview) ontop of another UIScrollView. Trying to get clarification on how to make this work.

So i made a UITableViewController subclass and add that as an object in my Mainview class.

```
@interface NRTableVC : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
      NSArray * tableLabelsArray;
}
@end
```

The table scrolls and displays OK.

But my

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Did select row");
}
```

method never gets called.

in my Mainview class I use it as follows

```
    RTable = [[[NRTableVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]autorelease];
[scrollview addSubview:RTable.view];
```

I was wondering so I need to somehow set self as the delegate or something like that.

Anybody able to give me some hints as to what is wrong?

Many Thanks,
Code

Comment: Does the table get populated with data correctly?

Comment: Yes table gets populated correctly. Only thing not working is the table will not respond to touches. When a cell gets pressed. The cell highlights but no call to 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' method.

Comment: Could you please log the following: RTable.view.dataSource and .delegate? Is the result of the log equal to your ViewController or Equal to RTable?

Comment: Do you see tables with empty cells?

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is, in the View I want the tableview is create an instance

I do this in ViewDidLoad or the LoadView methods

```
UITableView *tableView = [UITableView alloc] init...
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.datasource = self;
```

Then I add it as a subview of the current view.

This means your MainView needs to implement the tableView datasource and delegate methods.

Edit:

If you use interface builder, remember to drag the datasource and delegates to the fileowner

Comment: Thats the way I've always added tables to my views. But as i said above i subclassed it to try and learn a different way. Apparently Tables are not selectable while on a scrollview.

Comment: That does make sense, but rather than having 2 tables (seen in comment below) just use sections for 1 tableview?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set delegate for tableview? Without delegate set it won't call any delegate methods.

Comment: Yes I have with  self.tableView.delegate = self;

Comment: What you are probably missing is RTable.view.delegate = self

Comment: I cant do that. But I cant do RTable.tableView.delegate = self; Which will make the app crash. I'm guessing putting a UITableView inside a scrollableView is not meant to happen. I'll go back to the way I used to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Is anything retaining `RTable`? You're autoreleasing it but you don't show any code that indicates it's being retained anywhere.

Comment: Good, point. Also: it is not good practice to just add the view of a ViewController to some other VC's view as this means that several core methods of UIViewController are not called, including: viewDidLoad, undLoad, didAppear ...

Comment: It's added onto a view. So is retained by that while the view is alive.

Comment: addSubview increases retain count

Comment: @FelixLam, so you believe(know) its better to just add the UITableViews directly to the view rather than sub classing them?

Comment: I would believe that you probably do not need to subclass UITableviews and that you should not be mixing the views of two ViewControllers, but rather have one viewController. The one VC should then be the delegate and datasource to both tableViews. You can differentiate between the two tables within all delegate and datasource methods.

Comment: also: adding the view to another view increase the retainCount of the view not of its controller. Hence the VC will be release as soon as your autorelease-pool is drained. You should see a crash at some point.

Comment: @FelixLam That's what I was thinking, since `RTable` probably isn't even part of the view controller hierarchy, so there's nothing retaining it.